# Como atribuir split das linhas(Strings) de um vector a um elemento de um outro vector. Ex: v[linhaAntiga][elementoLinhaAntiga]

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

/*Função para fazer split*/
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string s, char c)
{
    std::string buff{""};
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    for(auto n:s)
    {
        if(n != c) buff+=n; 
        else if(n == c && buff != "") { v.push_back(buff); buff = ""; }
    }
    if(buff != "") v.push_back(buff);

    return v;
}
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    /*Quero passar os elementos(linhas) desse vector...*/
    std::vector<std::string> strOrigin;
    strOrigin.push_back("Uma frase legal aqui...");
    strOrigin.push_back("Uma frase mais legal ainda aqui");
    /*Para esse vector, de forma que eu possa acessar os elementos assim: strCurrent[i][j], onde i eram as linhas do meu vector antigo, e j são os elementos de cada linha*/ 
    std::vector<std::string> strCurrent;
    auto IteratorOrigin = strOrigin.begin();
    strCurrent.push_back(split(IteratorOrigin[0], ' '));

return 0;
}
```

Eu quero que um novo vector receba elementos das strings(linhas) que peguei de um outro vector, de forma que eu possa acessar, a partir do novo vector, dessa forma: nomeDoVector[i]//No elemento i desse vector, estariam os elementos da string da linha i do vector anterior[j]//e esse j seriam os elementos. O erro que está acontecendo com esse código é o seguinte:

```
exit status 1
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:28:43: error: could not convert 'strOrigin' from 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' to 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
  strCurrent.push_back(split(strOrigin, ' '));
```

Tá, eu preciso de um for para fazer com mais de uma linha de um vector, para dar uma automatizada, mas no caso, eu não consigo fazer nem com uma linha..... kkk

Answer (score 1):

Perceba que `strCurrent` é da classe `std::vector<std::string>`, isto é, um vetor cujos *elementos* pertencem à classe `std::string`. Mas você não quer que cada elemento desse vetor seja uma string, mas sim um *vetor* de strings, de modo a armazenar o resultado da função `split`.

A própria mensagem de erro diz que você está retornando `std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >` (ou seja, um `std::vector<std::string>`) da função `split`, e tentando usar esse objeto como argumento para `push_back()`, que espera um `std::__cxx11::string` (ou seja, `std::string`).

Para resolver seu problema, basta declarar `strCurrent` como

```
std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > strCurrent;
```

dentro da sua função `main()`.

Ainda, você pode definir uma função que executa o loop que você deseja:

```
std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > split(const std::vector<std::string> & strOrigin, const char separator)
{
  std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > strCurrent(strOrigin.size());
  for(auto&& line : strOrigin)
  {
    strCurrent.push_back( split(line, separator) );
  }
  return strCurrent;
}
```

Considere ainda introduzir o especificador `const` aos parâmetros da sua função e passar `s` por referência:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string & s, const char c);
```